# How can I make a javascript that sets the background color of an element to the innerhtml color code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As I'm making a style template for a website, I'd like to make span elements that from example blocks with a background color. Example:

`<span class='colblock'>#FF0000</span>`

should result in a block with color code #FF0000 (Red) as background color.

Currently, the following css and JS code is being used (relevant bits)
CSS

```
<style>
    span.colblock{
        margin:8px;
        padding:8px;
        display:block;
        border:1px solid black;
        border-radius:2px;
        width:66px;
    }
</style>
```

Javascript (On page bottom, just before body)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("colblock").each(function() {
        var ccode = $(this).html();
        $(this).css("background-color", ccode);
    });
</script>
```

IMO, this is supposed to work, but it does not. Can someone elighten me?

Comment: Instead of having content as color, you can have specific width and height with background-color: #FF0000

Comment: The `<`in your css definition is not correct.

Comment: The concept here is to make the span element use the color code inside itself as background color to avoid typing a load of CSS.

Comment: @reporter, Typo in the post... Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).text()` instead of `$(this).html()`

```
$(".colblock").each(function() {
        var ccode = $(this).text();
        $(this).css("background-color", ccode);
    });
```

And in your css `<span.colblock` should be like this: `span.colblock`

Answer (score 3):

While selecting element by class use `.` operator. You have error here:

```
$(".colblock").each(function() {
   ^ //missed '.' dot
```

Use following:

```
$(".colblock").each(function() {
    var ccode = $(this).html();
    $(this).css("background-color", ccode);
});
```

---

In css also you having typo:

```
<span.colblock{
^ //===> should be removed
```

See working [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3726tbr/)

Answer (score 1):

1. To select a class, you should use `$(".ClassName")`, here it will be `$(".colblock")`. 
   `$("colblock")` will select elements with tag name "colblock".
2. Your jquery link seems dead.

   `src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"`

   This one works as I tested:

   `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.1.min.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Not using JQuery

```
var the_Span = document.getElementById("colblock");
var span_Text = the_Span.innerText;
the_Span.style.backgroundColor = span_Text;
```